# What is the problem here. Google Earth Engine Error Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, api

Can't find out the problem here.

```
img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')\
    .filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-02-28')\
    .filterBounds(area)\
    .select(["VH"])
mome = img.mean()
areac = mome.clip(area)
skinny = ee.Kernel.gaussian({
  radius: 10,
  sigma: 1,
})
filt = areac.convolve(skinny)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-065f15fee587> in <module>()
      4 skinny = ee.Kernel.gaussian({
      5   radius: 10,
----> 6   sigma: 1,
      7 })
      8 filt = areac.convolve(skinny)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ee/ee_number.py in __init__(self, number)
     40     else:
     41       raise ee_exception.EEException(
---> 42           'Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): %s' % number)
     43 
     44   @classmethod

EEException: Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): {25: 10, 10: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using JavaScript syntax for the `ee.Kernel.gaussian` arguments. Use Python syntax instead:

```
img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')\
    .filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-02-28')\
    .filterBounds(area)\
    .select(["VH"])
mome = img.mean()
areac = mome.clip(area)
skinny = ee.Kernel.gaussian({
  'radius': 10,
  'sigma': 1,
})
filt = areac.convolve(skinny)
```

It looks like you have defined `radius = 25` and `sigma = 10` variables somewhere else in your script, as what you are passing to the kernel is `{25: 10, 10: 1}` otherwise you would have got a `NameError: name 'radius' is not defined` exception.

Comment: Ok done. Thank you.

Comment: @SubhadipDatta https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers